# Logical Mathematical Proofs

Tags: logic

1. Prove the following theorem:  ⊢ (P → Q) → (¬ Q → ¬ P)
2. Prove the following equivalence:  (P ∧ Q) → R    ⊣ ⊢     P → (Q → R)
3. Prove the following set of sentences inconsistent:
   {P → (Q → R), ¬ R ∧ (P ∧ Q)

Comment: What have you tried ? What proof system you are using ?

Comment: Hint for the first one: assume ¬ Q and derive ¬ P by contradiction.

Comment: For the 3rd one, use truth table.